"Associativity" and "commutativity" in joint entropy and joint distribution
I am studying entropy, joint entropy, and conditional entropy using the book Elements of Information Theory. Meanwhile, I am also studying a paper about information leakage analysis. I noticed that although the textbook usually only has necessary random variables in the expression:
$$H(Y|X)=H(X,Y) - H(X)$$
(The chain rule of joint and conditional entropy)
In real papers, there could be more than two random variables in the expression. For example:
$$H(X|Y,Z)=H(X,Y,Z)−H(Y,Z)$$
Which in the same textbook order should be:
$$H(X|(Y,Z))=H((Y,Z), X)−H(Y,Z)$$
Here, the authors of the paper seemed to switch the positions of X, Y, and Z arbitrarily in the joint entropy. Also, parentheses are removed. I think this is trivial in the random variable view because it just means the result tuple from three random variables in different orders. However, if I look down to the distribution view and by the textbook's proof:
\begin{align}H(X,(Y,Z)) & = \\ & 
-\sum_{x}\sum_{y,z} p(x,(y,z)) \log p(x, (y,z))& = \\ &
-\sum_{x}\sum_{y,z} p(x,(y,z)) \log p(x)p((y,z)|x)& = \\ &
-\sum_{x}\sum_{y,z} p(x,(y,z)) \log p(x) -\sum_{x}\sum_{y,z} p(x,(y,z))p((y,z)|x)& = \\ &
-\sum_{x}\log p(x) -\sum_{x}\sum_{y,z} p(x,(y,z))p((y,z)|x) & = \\ &
H(X) - H((Y,Z) | X)
\end{align}
Which looks would be different even if just the parentheses change in joint entropy? For example, if it becomes
\begin{align}H((X,Y),Z)) & = \\ & 
-\sum_{x,y}\sum_{z} p((x,y),z) \log p((x,y),z))& = \\ &
-\sum_{x,y}\sum_{z} p((x,y),z) \log p(x,y)p(z|(x,y))& = \\ &
-\sum_{x,y}\sum_{z} p((x,y),z) \log p(x,y) -\sum_{x,y}\sum_{z} p((x,y),z))p(z|(x,y))& = \\ &
-\sum_{x,y}\log p(x,y) -\sum_{x,y}\sum_{z} p((x,y),z)p(z|(x,y)) & = \\ &
H(X,Y) - H(Z|(X,Y))
\end{align}
I think there should be something about "associativity" and "commutativity" rules in the expression of entropy. I tried to search materials that mention them, but unfortunately, so far I have only found the simplest examples with few random variables in the entropy expression.

Could you be clearer about your question? As you say, there is a certain associativity and commutivity among the variables, which result from the symmetry between them and (I suppose) the associtivity and commutivity of real numbers. But what is the specific question? Are you looking for references? Are you confused by any part of this property?

Yes I am finding if there is any reference mentioning that arbitrarily setting parentheses or exchanging the random variables in joint entropy expression will cause different results (I'm not sure if the proof above is correct or not). I thought the textbook about entropy and probability would mention that, but maybe it is too trivial. Also, I think maybe it is because textbooks usually only put two random variables. So I wonder if there is a book or any material that mentions the idea of such  (no) "associativity" and (no) "commutativity" in entropy expressions.

Also I am confused by how paper authors simply operate at the random variable level of entropy and discard the distribution details. It looks fascinating that we seem able to manipulate random variables in entropy expressions like other symbols in algebra, but I got the impression that the abstraction of entropy is not high enough. So even H((X, Y), Z) != H(X, (Y, Z)) because the underlying distribution calculation for the chain rule will be different. But if we don't talk about the conversion between joint and conditional entropy, H((X, Y), Z) == H(X, (Y, Z)) may work again (not sure)
